# mount openwrt filesystem using sshfs

Tags: openwrt, sshfs

I'm trying to mount my `/tmp` directory on my router running OpenWrt "Chaos Calmer" in my local Ubuntu machine using `sshfs`.

I followed
https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/sshfs.server and http://bredsaal.dk/openwrt-and-sshfs

But I kep getting the following error:

```
sudo sshfs root@192.168.252.93:/mnt/ /home/hscuser/mount/ -o sshfs_debug,ssh_command="ssh -p 222"    
SSHFS version 2.5  
read: Connection reset by peer
```

I do not see any error messages in `dmesg` or `logread`.
Also, I can `ssh` & `scp` to my router without any issues.
I'm able to mount directories from another Ubuntu system.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: Can you `sftp`? Do you have `sftp-server` installed on the server and enabled?

Comment: Hi @Jakuje...I choose "openssh-sftp-server" from "Network->SSH" while making the image.  I can't use opkg to install the package (due to some network restrictions).  Are there some other package that needs to be selected as well.  I can see the "sftp-server" executable link in "/usr/libexec/" but not sure whether its started or not.

Comment: It should be enough. It is SSHD subsystem so when ssh is running, you are able to connect to sftp (on the same port) if it is configured in `sshd_config`.

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje. I do not see "/etc/ssh" directory on my board. Neither can i find the "sshd_config" file anywhere else. Seems that something is missing in the image.